# Fixed element in a vuetify.js v-sheet does not work

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I am developing a site with vuetify. I have this layout:

[image: Layout]

The problem is that I used display absolute in the copy-code icon, so if I scroll to the right the code, I get this:

[image: Layout]

If I try to set display from absolute to fixed, I do not know why, I find the icon no more in the code snippet but in the top-right corner of the page:

[image: Layout]

This is the code of the most inner component (the code snippet):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-fade-transition>
      <v-sheet class="code d-flex grey--text text--lighten-3 pa-4" :color="background" @mouseenter="showCopy = true" @mouseleave="showCopy = false">
        <v-fade-transition>
          <v-btn v-if="showCopy" flat icon class="copy" color="success lighten-3" @click="copyCode">
            <v-icon>content_copy</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-fade-transition>

        <v-layout column>
          <v-flex
            v-for="(row, index) of rows"
            :key="index"
            :class="getClass(index)"
            @mouseenter="rowEntered(index)"
            @mouseleave="rowLeft(index)"
            @click="rowClicked(index)"
          >
            <span class="orange--text text--lighten-3 mr-3 code-row">{{ getRowText(index + 1) }}</span>
            <span>{{ row }}</span>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-fade-transition>

    <v-snackbar v-model="showSnackbar" color="success">
      <span>Testo copiato negli appunti!!!</span>
      <v-btn dark flat @click="showSnackbar = false">Close</v-btn>
    </v-snackbar>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import copyToClipboard from 'copy-to-clipboard';

@Component({
  components: {}
})
export default class AppExamCardCode extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  readonly code!: string;

  readonly color = 'grey';
  readonly darkenDefault = 'darken-3';
  readonly darkenSelected = 'darken-2';
  showCopy = false;
  showSnackbar = false;
  hovered = -1;
  selected: number[] = [];

  get background(): string {
    return this.color + ' ' + this.darkenDefault;
  }

  get rows(): string[] {
    return this.code.split('\n');
  }

  //rowClicked, rowLeft, rowEntered, getClass(returns only row background color, getRowText), 

  copyCode(): void {
    copyToClipboard(this.code);
    this.showSnackbar = true;
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.code {
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Inconsolata", monospace;
  white-space: pre;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.code-row {
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}

.copy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
```

This is where it is contained: (AppExamCardCodeExercise)

```
<template>
  <div class="code-exercise">
    <app-exam-card-code :code="exercise.code" />
    <app-exam-card-code-answer :solution="exercise.solution" :showAnswers="showAnswers"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Contained in AppExamCardExercise:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <app-exam-card-true-or-false-exercise v-if="isTrueOrFalse" :showAnswers="showAnswers"/>
    <app-exam-card-code-exercise v-else :showAnswers="showAnswers"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Contained in AppExamCard:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-scale-transition>
      <v-card v-if="show" class="exam-card" :class="cardClass" flat>
        <!-- omitted -->
        </v-toolbar>

        <v-card-text>
          <v-slide-y-transition mode="out-in">
            <v-layout row pa-5 :key="current">
              <v-flex xs12>
                <app-exam-card-score v-if="isFinished && showScore" />
                <app-exam-card-exercise v-else :showAnswers="showAnswers" />
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-slide-y-transition>
        </v-card-text>

        <v-card-actions>
          <!-- omitted -->
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-scale-transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the copy icon is `position: absolute` and your code block (with the scrollbar) is `position: relative`, so it scrolls together.

Set your code block to `position: static` and then wrap it in a `div` and set that div to `position: relative`, so the copy-button is relative to the parent-parent div (which is not scrollable)

HTML

```
<div class="fix">
  <code>
    <span class="copy">Copy</span>
    [...]
  </code>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fix {
  position: relative;
}
.fix code {
  position: static;
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/voxp8rgf/1/

Comment: Great, it worked! Thank you. Can I ask you why does this work and why position: fixed; on the copy button did not? I also did not know position static

Comment: @EuberDeveloper `position: static` is just the default value of `position`. `Position: absolute` looks for the first parent with `position: relative` and positions itself relative to that. And `position: fixed` basically ignores all parents and positions itself relative to the window.